mysqli_ping is deprecated. What should I replace it with?
I was using mysqli_ping() to check if the mysqli connection was up. In the latest PHP 8.4 version, this function was deprecated and will be removed in the future. Why is this function deprecated, what can I replace it with, and was I wrong to use it in the first place?

You can replace with with something simple like this:
try {
    $mysqli->query('DO 1');
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception) {
    // Establish new connection
}

But you probably shouldn't!
This function was never intended to check if the connection is alive. Note that it throws an error if the connection is down. Its purpose was to reconnect automatically when PHP was compiled with libmysql. This is no longer possible. Since PHP 8.2, this function throws an error when the connection is down, just like any other mysqli function. Automatic reconnect is a terrible idea, which is why it was never implemented in mysqlnd. Since mysqli_ping() cannot perform its core task anymore, it is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

With no offence to any fellow developers, but if you are doing something like this you are already doing something wrong:
try {
    $mysqli->ping();
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception) {
    // Establish new connection
}

The code above leads to one of two things:

You know exactly at which point in your code the connection may be down
You execute this before every single mysqli function

If 1 is true then why not just destroy the old object and create a new connection?
If 2 is true then you are suffering a serious performance penalty for something that may rarely happen. A MySQL connection rarely drops. If yours is dropping often then you need to debug and fix whatever the root cause for that may be. Is it timeout on the MySQL server, some network issue, or maybe something else? Instead of using a try-catch, it's better to let the code error out and have PHP log the error message so you can investigate the issue.
Checking if mysqli connection is alive is probably never needed. After all, PDO doesn't have a method to do so and it's the preferred extension to connect to databases.
